# How to remove english input from japanese keyboard in windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-layout, language

I have an english and japanese keyboard on my win 10 PC. Japanese one has two input modes: hiragana and regular english (romaji) and the second one doubles my english keyboard. Is there any way to remove it so my japanese keyboard will only write hiragana?

[image]

[image]